# Get value of textfield from the Alertview n reload that value in Tableview

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uialertview

can anyone tell me how to fetch alertbox's text field data based on button clicked in the alertbox.

i.e. I am using one tableview which contains some row.now when user clicks on 'Add', it prompts one alertview with textfield in it and containing two buttons 1.Ok 2.Cancel

now if Ok is pressed, then entered text will be reloaded to the table.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
  forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
{
    [arry removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView1 reloadData];
} else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
{
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:@"Enter Name Here" 
                          message:@"blank" 
                          delegate:self 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK!", nil];

    UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 260, 25)];

    /*CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 60);

    [alert setTransform:myTransform];*/

    [myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [alert addSubview:myTextField];

    /*How to get textfield text in the Table from here */
    [alert show];

}
```

}

Comment: Declare this textfield in your .h file and then use it wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

as per your code the below one will give you the texfield

```
    UITextField* textField = (UITextField*)[alertView.subviews objectAtIndex:5];
NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
```

implement this in alertView delegate to get the textField value.